# Call Ajax from PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I want to do an ajax call in a php file. (the final goal is to get a localStorage).
If I have well understood
i begin with a start session in the php.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Then, ajax call of another php file.

```
<script>
    src="jquery.js";
    var variableToSend = 'foo';
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        async : false,
        url: "/login_getStorage.php",
        data: { variable: variableToSend }
    });
</script>
```

In this file php login_getStorage.php I have only

```
<?php
$_SESSION['toto'] = "titi";
```

If I have well understood, the variable $_SESSION['toto'] should be initialized everywere with "titi"

So in the main file :(so after script)

```
<?php
echo($_SESSION['toto'] );
```

I thought it will display 'titi'.
But I have the error PHP Notice:  Undefined index: toto

It seems that my ajax call is not done

How can we do to do this ajax call ?

Best regards.

Comment: I *think* the problem is probably that the first PHP script is done, dusted and finished before the Ajax call takes place - so if the session variable is set in the script called over Ajax you'll not see it in the first script until you reload the page. [This QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming) might help explain the situation better.

Comment: So how can I do the ajax call withour dusting the php ?

Comment: set async : true in ajax and try again !

Comment: What you'd generally do in the script you're calling over Ajax is echo out a JSON representing the state change, which you use in the `success()` callback to do what you need to do (set what you want in `localStorage`); you can't *go back* to PHP at that point as it runs on the server not the client.

Comment: @BhAvikGajjar : Thanks but it does not work.

Comment: @CD001 : So what can we do ? Can you detail the solution ?

Comment: It depends on what *exactly* you're trying to do - [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php) should cover the specifics of using Ajax/jQuery. As an aside though, you realise there's a typo in your code here? `<script> ... src="jquery.js";` should be `<script src="jquery.js">` - since `src` is an HTML attribute of the `<script>` tag.

Comment: I correct the typo, but it does not change anything.

Comment: To answer better what I want to do :  In the beginning of php (session_start), I have something in the local storage. So I want to retreive this. So as it is impossible to access to localStorage inside php I try to do an ajax call.

Comment: What do you want PHP to do with that data from `localStorage` ? I've got a feeling you're sort of approaching the problem backwards - but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> In this file php login_getStorage.php I have only
>
> ```
> <?php
> $_SESSION['toto'] = "titi";
> ```

You need to call [`session_start()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before you can use `$_SESSION['toto']` in any PHP file.

Your Ajax call is probably working just fine, but since you are editing the contents of a session that doesn't exist, it isn't having the effect you want.

Comment: Thank you, session_start is needed but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

> `PHP` is run on the server **BEFORE** any of the `javascript` is
>   parsed.

There are a few questions:

- Did you include the jquery library?
- Are there any `JS` errors?

Try to add the `success` to your `ajax`:

```
success: function(data){ 
    // when success
}
```

Your `PHP` is run before your `ajax` call so the value doesn't exist on page load.
Instead of assigning a value on the `PHP` page you can also return a value.

```
<script>
    src="jquery.js";
    var variableToSend = 'foo';
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        async : false,
        url: "/login_getStorage.php",
        data: { variable: variableToSend },
        success: function(data){ 
           // when success display data 
           alert(data); // alert the session value
        }
    });
</script>
```

And then your `login_getStorage.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION['toto'] = "titi";
echo $_SESSION['toto'];
```